# How to add Hebrew dictionary to iOS built in dictionary?

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, dictionary

I want to buy iPad Air, but before i do that, i need to know how i can translate hebrew in iPad with a tap. I need that for translating words i don't know in books and articles, for improving my english language. I tried to add (in the iphone) hebrew dictionary to the iOS built in dictionary, but i failed. I need other solution for that, it's so important to me, and that the only reason i want to buy iPad.

Note: It's important that i can translate without internet.

Thanks.

Comment: Let us know how that works out, because it's a good idea for an app.  I think the biggest problem you're going to have is the sheer data size of a full translation dictionary.

Comment: I don't built iOS built dictionary to know how its work.
Yes, this is a big idea for app, but i wonder If it exists or not.

Comment: Oh, I know.  I'm not mocking you.  But what you're suggesting is an app that could run in the background at all times, and respond to your clicking a word, and show a definition in a different language.  That's an enormous amount of information to hold on a local device.

Comment: I don't want to built an app for that. I want to add Hebrew dictionary to iOS built in dictionary, and that resolve my problem.

Comment: Someone? That important.